# Sonar- Grant and revoke project-level permissions for mentioned projects

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I have Sonar installed in my machine and integrated with Jenkins.There are around 30 projects and to view detail info of each project I use same admin credentials.I am looking for steps which can help me in below.

1- How can I create a user credentials so that the user can see few projects out of 30 under sonar.
2- I have created a new user like below.

[image]
Created Different Users

[image]
Under each project I have assigned Users and Groups

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What were the results? What about [the docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization) isn't clear?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam I have updated my question with my analysis. I got stuck with assigning projects to particular users. I have followed the Sonar docs but I was not understanding them

Comment: please crop and re-post your screenshots. As-is they are very difficult to use.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam I have completed this using https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization . Thank you